# Youtube API: Displaying thumbnails of each video...?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

Hi can someone assist me with the proper way to get the **default.jpg** image for every video from the channels i'm pulling in?

```
<?php
$url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/utahblaze/uploads?orderby=updated&max-results=8';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach ($xml->entry as $entry) :

    $kids = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
    $attributes = $kids->group->content[0]->attributes();
    $flv = $attributes['url'];
    $attributes = $kids->group->player->attributes();
    $link = $attributes['url']; 
?>

<a href="<?=$link?>">test</a?
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: What **default.jpg**, the 480x360 thumbnail image?

Comment: @salathe no I think its smaller than that, probably something like 100x80 or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it's an example of how you could get the image url of a video using the GData Youtube class of Zend Framework.

```
<?php 
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
$query = $yt->newVideoQuery();
$query->videoQuery = 'cat';
$query->startIndex = 10;
$query->maxResults = 20;
$query->orderBy = 'viewCount';

$videoFeed = $yt->getVideoFeed($query);

foreach ($videoFeed as $videoEntry) : ?>
    <div class="video"> 
        <span>Title: <?php echo $videoEntry->getVideoTitle();?><span><br />
        <span>Description:<?php echo $videoEntry->getVideoDescription();?> </span> <br/>
        <?php $videoThumbnails = $videoEntry->getVideoThumbnails(); ?>
        <img alt="video-thumbnail" src="<?php echo $videoThumbnails[0]['url'];?>" />
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

As you can see the getVideoThumbnails() method gives you an array of thumbnails for that video and their url inside. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the GData class instead of dealing with the Youtube API directly? I'd recommend you to use the official class which is bundled in the zend framework package as it will be easier to you to pull specific data from the video feeds. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.youtube.html

Comment: can you help me with an example, i dont see how it can get the ID or image thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice PHP class for embedding Youtube videos and playlists. It gives you thumbnails, and all other information / elements associated with the video.

[PHP Youtube Class](http://www.ssdtutorials.com/freebies.html)